# How do I port my PositiveSSL certs to Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elb

I have working PositiveSSL certs that I registered via Namecheap through Comodo.

What do I upload to ELB's Certificate Body and Certifcate Chain fields?

The email Comodo sent only contains the .ca-bundle + .crt files.  A lot of the tutorials that exist reference 4 files in that email.

Comment: t is base64-encoded and placed between a -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- header and an -----END CERTIFICATE----- footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ca-bundle should be the chain.  If it is rejected as invalid, then the file is most likely built upside down, so you need to completely reverse the ordering of the blocks in the file.  You can do this in a text editor.  There are usually only 2 or 3 blocks there, so reversing them is straightforward.  I have no idea why some CAs build these upside down, but they do.

The .crt should be the certificate body.

The private key is on the machine where you generated the CSR to request the certificates.

Note that it is *much* easier to import the certificate into Amazon Certificate Manager, first, and then select that certificate when you configure the load balancer for SSL, because if you get it wrong when building the balancer, you have to start over.  It's also easier to see your certs in one place if you import them into ACM.  There is no compelling reason to do it the "old" way.